# How to accept text input from a pygame GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, textinput

I am working on a RPG game using Python and Pygame, and am trying to make a two-part GUI, including a lower part that is like the basic command line, and a top part that will show all graphical "action."

What I need to find out is a way to include both in a pygame window, instead of using a pygame window and terminal window. As well, are there any Pygame GUI toolkits that would be appropriate for this use?

Thanks All!

Comment: That is more or less the same thing I am doing and while it looks like ezText is good and I will probably use it, I will just advise everyone against pgu. It is poorly documented and making anything work is difficult.

Comment: Although if you still need an input this file looks like a promising start: http://www.pygame.org/pcr/inputbox/inputbox.py

Comment: Actually this appears to gather events from the entire pygame session so never mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest using ezText instead?
It's a cool way to add text inupt bars to pygame. I used it before my self, and It's really easy to use.

http://www.pygame.org/project-EzText-920-.html

(feel free to leave a comment if you want help using it, although everything you need to know is in the example.py that comes with it)

Comment: Is there any easy way to identify if the text input is in the "foreground" (it was the last thing clicked on)? Because it would be best if it only took in events and was updated if this was the case, and I am having a hard time making it do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries) for a whole list of ToolKits for both Pygame and Pyglet. Albow (http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Albow/) has worked well for me in the past.

The easiest way to accomplish what you're talking about would be to make two Surfaces, one for each part of the interface, and then constantly update them in separate modules to finally blit them every frame. That way your main module can be simplified to something like:

```
import action_gui
import cl_gui
import pygame

pygame.init()
MAIN_SURF = pygame.display.set_mode((x, y))
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')

while (True):
    action_surf = action_gui.update()
    cl_surf = cl_gui.update()
    MAIN_SURF.blit(action_surf, my_position_1)
    MAIN_SURF.blit(cl_surf, my_position_2)
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Very cool (and useful :D). I dont think I will use this, but thanks for the answer! I'm sure i will be able to use this eventually!